# What happens if one of your committee members die after your initial submission?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee

There is one of the members of my committee that is extremely old (like 80+) and smokes like a chimney. I was already wary of my supervisor pretty much forcing me to include him in my jury committee. Right now he is, supposedly, the only member that has to submit his comments after my initial submission, and every day that goes by I am more and more concerned that he might fall ill or die. What would normally happen if he dies or some debilitating illness doesn't permit him to evaluate me? Would I have to submit to another member of the jury and wait again for my evaluation?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/are-purely-hypothetical-questions-allowed).

Comment: I'm voting to close, because only but people in this student's program aware of their own rules and procedures can correctly answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

The straight answer to your question, as posted, is: check the rules of your program.

However, I'll answer a related question: How should you prepare in case a committee member dies?

You should get an extra committee member, and ask them to read your thesis. Explain that the old committee member has not evaluated your thesis and that you are concerned. With this strategy, you get the ball rolling. In case your old committee member dies, the extra member is already up to speed and ready to take over without having to restart the process.

However, don't count on it! If he's 80 and smoking, chances are he will live to be 200, and bury YOU :)

Comment: That last statement :D ... It's kind of true... I also wondered why professors with such a great career never retire at old age!

Answer (score 1):

Who knows? It depends on the specific rules in your institution, which may or may not cover this particular situation. If there is no rule in your institution for that case, than someone in power will make a decision when necessary. Usually, the institution tries to be reasonable when something like this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your university will require a certain number of committee members.  If you fall below the minimum, then a new one must be added.

It is too late for you now, but in general I suggest having an extra committee member.